# Is there any way to do RTMPE and SWF verification on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, rtmp

I already know that RTMPE is done through Flash and that even when you compile flash down to run as an iPhone application that one of the things that specifically doesn't work is RTMPE.

I just want to make sure that I'm correct in assuming that there is no way to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use librtmp built for iOS as a method for playing a media file via rtmpe protocol.

In essence, it would be going down to C and creating a player (that supports skips if necessary) or using rtmpdump.

When/if you do get into this, please note that a C file cannot have a main method in Objective-C (without extensive modification) so be sure to rename the main method found in rtmpdump to something else. Then, it is relatively easy to interact with it. Alternatively, I'll upload an Objective-C version that emulates rtmpdump by modifying some files found on Github if necessary...

Some People to Check Out on Github: saiten, BigBadOwl, idevsoftware

Answer (score 0):

Right. No way. Flash isn't supported in Mobile Safari and RTMPE is done in-player.